# How dictionaries behave

Tags: python, dictionary

Here's the code:

```
checkDictionary = {
    '0': (print('0'),0),
    '1': (print('1'),1),
    '2': (print('2'),2)
    }


print(checkDictionary.get('1','Not found'))
```

The output I expected was:

```
1
(None, 1)
```

but instead it runs all the functions in every value field:

```
0
1
2
(None, 1)
```

Can anyone explain this behavior, and why was it implemented like this?

I heard from multiple sources that Python dictionaries are supposed to be O(1) fast "most of the time".

So the thing I really wanted to accomplish was to make a nice switch/case with multiple executing lines:

```
def readPoint(v):
    print(f'Point: {v}')

def readLine(v):
    print(f'Line: {v}')

Point = 1
Line = 2
segment = [1,1]
checkDictionary = {
    Point: "geometry = readPoint(segment)\n__type='Point'",
    Line: "geometry = readLine(segment)\n__type='Line'"
    }


exec(checkDictionary.get(segment[0],'raise ValueError("Some error")'))
```

Would there be some issues with this design pattern? don't care about the functions or variables they are only examples.

Comment: The print statements execute when `checkDictionary` is declared and the dictionary is left full of literals i.e. `{'0': (None, 0), '1': (None, 1), '2': (None, 2), '3': (None, 3), '4': (None, 4), '5': (None, 5), '6': (None, 6), '7': (None, 7)}`.

Comment: It's not clear to me how any of the rest of your question relates to the last sentence. This isn't at all specific to dictionaries, a list `[(print('0'), 0)]` would also print when defined then contain `(None, 0)`.

Comment: The print function was put in there as example. I tried at first to put som exec function to run multiple lines of code, but was struct seeing that all my exec lines were run nevertheless if it coinsided with my key value.

Answer (score 2):

This is totally expected and in no way a *strange* behavior. The key to understanding is knowing that the dictionary gets created (keys and values are evaluated) when you declare it.

**In your case, the evaluation of the values results in the execution of the `print` statements.**

This is why you get:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Then comes `print(checkDictionary.get('1','Not found'))`

which expectedly produces:

```
(None, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, so instead if I want a function to go in as a value I can make it a string and evaluate the result.

Comment: you could but evaluating strings can be a [pandora's box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandora%27s_box).

Comment: @PaalPedersen functions are first class in Python, you can put them in as values *if you don't call them*. Look into `lambda` or `functools.partial` for creating callables with preset arguments. I wouldn't recommend stringifying and evaluating.

Answer (score 0):

It does it because anywhere you're calling `print` it will print, so the best way to solve this is to remove the print or something else and also `print` is a none type

Actually `(None, 1)` is the output of the code, it's just that when you're creating the dictionary it is printing

so at the end your code is working as expected